# How to skip binary files in artifacts configuration in TeamCity

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, build-automation, teamcity, artifacts

I work on a .NET solution and I want to download source code and binaries from TeamCity. This is why I configured build artifacts. My configuration of the artifacts paths

```
src\app\Debug\* => debug
src\**\* => source
```

[image]

So far so good. But I want to skip some folders in the artifact, for example in the source artifact I want to skip

**source\app\Debug**

Are there any easy solution for that? Many thanks!

P.S. Once this question sorted I will zip the artifacts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, all your binaries have been built into `src/app/Debug`
What about building them into another folder, outside of `src` folder? Like a `binaries` folder at the root.
Your configuration of the artifacts paths should be something like this:

```
binaries\app\Debug\* => debug
src\**\* => source
```

Comment: This actually sounds really good. I will wait for a few days to see other answers, but I voted up your solution. Thanks!